# Php sending isset to the ajax and the inner of the ajax is not reading that isset

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I want to know how to do an isset readable for the view.

My code:

fetch.php

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC))
 {
<div class="blog-entry">
  <div class="label__title"><?php echo $row['title'];?></div>
  <div class="label__description"><?php echo $row['text'];?></div>
  <div class="label__time"> <div class="calendar-icon"></div> <?php echo 
   $row['date'];?></div>
   <?php
     if(isset($_SESSION['user'])) {
   ?>
   <a href="php/delete_post.php?id=<?php echo $row['id'] 
   ?>" class="label__delete">Elimina entrada</a>
   <?php
     }
   ?>
 </div>
```

then I have an ajax with an innerhtml.

ajax.js

```
var content = document.getElementById("result_para");
 content.innerHTML = content.innerHTML+response;
```

The problem is that the inner doesn't print the if(isset... of the php

Comment: You should start debugging by checking if the session id was passed correctly with the AJAX request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This the AJAX call

```
function getInfo() {
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            var content = document.getElementById("result_para");
            content.innerHTML = content.innerHTML + this.responseText;
        }
    };
    xhttp.open("GET", 'results.php', true);
    xhttp.send();
}
```

My test `PHP` file `results.php`

```
<?php
session_start();
// $_SESSION['user'] = 'julekgwa'; test before setting session
$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "000000", "ng_app");

// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    die();
}
$result = $conn->query('SELECT * FROM `blog`');
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) : ?>
<div class="blog-entry">
    <div class="label__title"><?php echo $row['title']; ?></div>
    <div class="label__description"><?php echo $row['text']; ?></div>
    <div class="label__time">
        <div class="calendar-icon"></div> <?php echo $row['date']; ?></div>
    <?php if (isset($_SESSION['user']))  : ?>
        <!-- this part will only be visible only, if the user $_SESSION['user'] is set -->
        <a href="php/delete_post.php?id=<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" class="label__delete">Elimina entrada</a>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
</div>
```

Results of the above code.
[image]

After setting session `$_SESSION['user']`, the content of the `if (isset($_SESSION['user']))` will be sent to AJAX too.

```
$_SESSION['user'] = 'julekgwa'; // after commenting out this line in the results file, the if (isset($_SESSION['user'])) will be executed
```

This are the results
[image]

This part of the code will only execute only if this is set `$_SESSION['user']`, you need to start the session on the pages that you use sessions with `session_start();` before your code.

```
<?php
if (isset($_SESSION['user'])) {
    ?>
    <a href="php/delete_post.php?id=<?php echo $row['id']
    ?>" class="label__delete">Elimina entrada</a>
    <?php
}
?>
```

Comment: Sorry, but is not full of errors. The code I wrote in this fetch.php example contains all you wrote there (exept that last </div> is inside the loop) but I didn't paste it cause I wanted to show where is the main problem. Fetch php connects with the db, gets some data with a select query and then with this while prints all the entries and then I send this to the ajax.js (the ajax with the inner will print it in the dom). So I wrote this post cause I wanted to know how I can avoid using isset in the while loop cause when the ajax gets this dom data escape all after the <?php

Comment: Thanks, I forgot to write the session_start().

Comment: Sorry I'm new here. What do you mean?